# Why are my TABLEAU table aggregation attempts ignoring my filter?

Tags: sql, data-visualization, tableau-api

See attached image. Via Coursera, I am new to Tableau so what I am attempting to do seems it should be rather simple to do but isn't (not intuitively so). I'm familiar enough with SQL to wrangle my way around subqueries and case statements and such, but Tableau feels far more clunky most of the time.

[Screenshot of Tableau worksheet table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4C5b.png)

I simply want to aggregate the dollar amounts listed on the right, SUM'ed across each City partition. Each city has a number of properties that have already been purposely filtered out, based on their profit Rank (via calculated fields) being too low. I've tried all sorts of things, but *the issue I'm facing is that the closest I can get is that **any SUM I do lumps in the properties that were filtered out despite the filter remaining in place on the Filter card** *. (I think I got a Running_Sum to yield the correct city totals a couple of times, but I couldn't get it to only show a single row of the final value for each city.)

I've tried countless variations and combinations of Include, Exclude, Fixed, Case, If, some nested via one or more of them, some not nested at all, some within a single calculated field, some spread out across multiple calculated fields...and often getting errors regarding not being able to mix aggregates and non-aggregates, being required to use aggregates in LODs but not being able to do so with IF statements, etc. But again, *the times I've been able to get it to "work" error-free, I get the SUM across **all** properties in the city..not just the ones in the 'INVEST' category that the filter suddenly ignores after any error-free modification attempts to what is seen here.*

Any help regarding this specific issue would be greatly appreciated, but a more general understanding of how to keep filters from being conditionally ignored by Tableau would be great. Sometimes the filter variable's second category would disappear as an option altogether while Tableau would still use rows from that category in the calculation. What gives? Thanks!

Comment: Use Analysis from the ribbon at the top. Then select Totals and, Add All Subtotals

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Sounds perfect and intuitive, but doing that is subtotaling each row in the viz instead of totaling across each City. The only other alternative appears to be to grand total the entire thing. Any idea how to control the level of detail on Totals?

Comment: Some features in Tableau that you can start to learn about that will help with different kinds of totals are 1. table calculations and 2. Level of Detail (LOD) calculations. Both are useful but have nuances that will take bit to learn. Not as quick and easy as hitting a button, but will give you more control when you need it.

Comment: Alex, that's what I've been digging into for days now and it doesn't seem to be helping with this particular issue but so much. Playing around with various combinations of both of Table Calculations and LOD is precisely the issue here: a very explicitly decalred Filter often seems to be ignored no matter what TCs and LODs I use.

Comment: ...On one worksheet, the variable on the filter shelf has both categories to choose from and is affecting the viz as desired, but on another worksheet that exact same variable on the Filter shelf only has one category to choose from when I go to edit it. Why could this be?